# Adding an alias to a secondary domain using domain API

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-domain-api

I'm trying, without any success, to add an alias to a secondary domain in my google apps for work using domain api.

In [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295?hl=en) article it's written: Domain aliases for secondary domains must be added via the Domains API

Using APIs Explorer I tried this query:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/domains?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "domainName": "primarydomain.com",
 "domainAliases": [
  {
   "parentDomainName": "secondarydomain.com",
   "domainAliasName": "secondarydomainalias.it",
   "verified": false
  }
 ]
}
```

but I get the following error

```
>     409 Conflict
>     
>     - Hide headers -
>     
>     Cache-Control:  private, max-age=0
>     Content-Encoding:  gzip
>     Content-Length:  136
>     Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
>     Date:  Thu, 18 Feb 2016 16:35:14 GMT
>     Expires:  Thu, 18 Feb 2016 16:35:14 GMT
>     Server:  GSE
>     Vary:  Origin, X-Origin
>     
>     {
>      "error": {
>       "errors": [
>        {
>         "domain": "global",
>         "reason": "duplicate",
>         "message": "Domain is already set up."
>        }
>       ],
>       "code": 409,
>       "message": "Domain is already set up."
>      }
>     }
```

Anyone with the same issue found a solution?

Bests

Alder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I re-read your question and my answer is changed as I see the problem - both your POST endpoint and data are incorrect.

The correct endpoint is 
`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/<customerId>/domainaliases`

and the correct data is

```
{
  "domainAliasName": secondarydomainalias.it,
  "parentDomainName": secondarydomain.com
}
```

You can try this here on the [domain aliases insert page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/domainAliases/insert)

You will need your domain's "customerId" to make these requests, get it by doing a [get on a user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get#try-it) in the domain.

Comment: tried  listing existing primary and secondary domains and got this (shortened):

`{ 
...
 "domains": [
  {
   ...
   "domainName": "primarydomain.com",
   "domainAliases": [
    {
     ...
     "domainAliasName": "primarydomain.it",
     "parentDomainName": "primarydomain.com",
     ...
    }
   ],
   "isPrimary": true,
 ...
  },
  {
   ...
   "domainName": "secondarydomain.com",
   "isPrimary": false,
   ...
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: same issue.The endpoint remains the same, POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/<I_placed_my_id_here>/domains?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
and I got the same error....any idea?

Comment: The correct endpoint ends with "domainaliases" while you are using "domains".

Comment: Ok, understood. I was looking at the wrong webpage. Using the one you linked everything works fine. Thanks a lot!